# Negative mass density in cosmology?

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, astronomy, space-expansion, density

I came across a problem in Chapter 6 of *An Introduction to Modern Cosmology* by Andrew Liddle that reads:

> Identify a sufficient and necessary condition that must be satisfied by the equation of state if $q_0$ is to be negative.

Here, $q_0$ is the deceleration parameter.

The hint given is to look at the acceleration equation:

> $\frac {\ddot a}{a} = -\frac{4\pi G}{3}(\rho +\frac{3p}{c^2})$

Now, $\ddot a$ must be positive for a negative $q_0$. So, I finally got the following condition:

> $p<-\frac{\rho c^2}{3}$

My question is, does this equation really have any physical interpretation?

Or is it that the author wants the reader to work out this relation to see why the model of the universe described till that point in the book is not sufficient to explain the observation that the universe is expanding with positive acceleration? The next chapter introduces the Cosmological Constant.

Comment: A fun novelty of the historical origins of the cosmological model that we still talk about a "deceleration parameter" even though it is now well established that the universe is accelerating! This is related to the nature of dark energy and the cosmological constant. I assume your next chapter will dive into the cosmological constant further, but there are certainly some number of physical interpretations out there for the nature of dark energy.